# Matching in order new line text content

Tags: java, regex

I have the following inputs that are consumed by a system:

```
-- file 1 (input) --
Test
One: any junk here
Two: any junk here
Three: any junk here
```

-

```
-- file 2 (input)
Test
One: any junk here
Three: any junk here
```

Being since file1 and file2 overlap, my ONE_THREE regex (below) is always matching file1 before my ONE_TWO_THREE can match it.

How can I be more specific in my regexs so that file 1 is only matched by ONE_TWO_THREE and file 2 is only matched by ONE_THREE (without moving the regexs around in the if statement)?

```
// text string represents random input stream...in this case it's set to file1 contents for literary content to illustrate my parsing regex issue. It would be set set to file 2 per other incoming messages to the system.  Either way it represents an incoming file contents.                                                                                                                                                                                                              
String text = "Test\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        + "One: any junk here\nTwo: any junk here\nThree: any junk here";                                                                                                                                                                            
Pattern ONE_THREE = Pattern.compile("^(One:\\s(.*)Three:\\s(.*))$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);                                                                                                                                             
Pattern ONE_TWO_THREE = Pattern.compile("^(One:\\s(.*)Two:\\s(.*))$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);                                                                                                                                           

Matcher m = null;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
if ( ((m = ONE_THREE.matcher(text)).find()) ||                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        ((m = ONE_TWO_THREE.matcher(text)).find()) ) {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    // How can I make sure to only match ONE_TWO without moving it up in the if statement?                                                                                                                                                           
    System.out.println("matched: " + m.pattern().toString());   // matches ONE_THREE    
    //
    // delete everything but "Test" for any input
    text = m.replaceAll("");                                                                     
    text = text .replaceAll("[\n]+$", "");  // delete any remaining /n                           
    System.out.println(text);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```

**NOTE**:
I'm trying to track the number of instances that are matched by regex type so I need to keep them separate. Is there a way to guarantee via reg ex ONE_THREE such that it only matches if "One:" on it's own line is directly followed "Three:" on the next line only (that way it won't match file1)?

Comment: What is the variable `text`? Is it a concatenation of the two files?

Comment: @Daemon: Sorry! See edit.  Essentially it's the file string contents.

Comment: If you want to count the number of times a regular expression matches text in a particular file, wouldn't it make sense to read the files into two separate strings (one for file 1, another for file 2) and then run a `Matcher` on the strings individually?

Comment: @Daemon: Yes, but text represents random input from either file 1 or file 2.  I just hard coded it to file 1 because that causes the issue.  At any given time they system receives input from file 1 or file 2 and you can thing of text containing that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you could change it to this

```
 #  "^(One:\\s((?:(?!Two:|Three:).)*)Three:\\s(.*))$"

 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      One: \s 
      (                             # (2 start)
           (?:
                (?! Two: | Three: )
                . 
           )*
      )                             # (2 end)
      Three: \s 
      ( .* )                        # (3)
 )                             # (1 end)
 $
```